# How many numbers have more primes than half that number?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

If I have a number $n$ and I count all the prime numbers below $n$, for how many numbers will there be more primes below $n$ than half of $n$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate

Comment: @vadim123 so... None?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Taking the fact that $1$ is not usually counted a prime, how many prime even numbers are there below $n$?

Comment: Approximately $\frac{n}{\ln(n)}$ which is almost always smaller than $\frac{n}{2}$, but there are a few numbers for which the condition **does** hold (namely $3$, $5$ and $7$)... right?

Comment: @barakmanos approximately half of the numbers below $n$ are even. If $1$ is not counted as prime the number of primes below $3$ is $1$ and half of $3$ is $1.5$.

Comment: Oh, I took "below" as inclusive, thanks...